# unable to load pwa element 'pwa-camera-modal'

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

Using the capacitor camera plugin, I'm trying to take photos with the camera on ionic. Unfortunately, whenever I call the function to launch the camera on a browser platform, I get this error:

```
unable to load pwa element 'pwa-camera-modal'
```

Once this happens, a dialogue is opened prompting me to upload an image, rather than the computer's webcam. How do I circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From capacitor:

> Some Capacitor plugins, such as Camera or Toast, have web-based UI
> available when not running natively.This UI is implemented using web components. Due to the magic of Shadow DOM, these components should not conflict with your own UI. To enable these controls, you must add @ionic/pwa-elements to your app.

And here's how to go about enabling it:

1. `npm install @ionic/pwa-elements`
2. In your `app.component.ts` file, import `defineCustomElements` from the `pwa-elements` you just installed, and then call it in the class controller:

Code:

```
import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';

...

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    defineCustomElements(window);
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that Ionic/Capacitor recommends doing this in main.ts, not in AppComponent - https://capacitorjs.com/docs/web/pwa-elements